# Background-repeat: space seems to stop working when parent gets too wide

Tags: css, safari, background-image, background-repeat

I've been playing around with `space` and `round` values for `background-repeat`. In theory this should mean I can use a radial gradient to create a nice dotted border on an element without the dots being cut off.

```
.test {
  background-repeat: space no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red calc(100% - 1px), transparent 100%);
  transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  background-position: left top;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 310px;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/momiwokena/1/edit?css,output

It works nicely in Chrome, but in Safari once the element gets too wide it stops working resulting in cut off dots on the right hand side.

How can I make Safari not cut off the dots?

**EDIT:** This has been raised with Apple.

Comment: Round and space can be used interchangeably here.

Comment: Seems like you should report this to the Safari folks. I tried with svg background and still it was getting cut off, so definitely looks like a bug in their background-repeat implementation.

Comment: Works well with Portable Opera version 64.0.3417.83.

Comment: Raised with Apple - https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7420231

Comment: Hi! I don't have installed Safari. But it exists some metatags that could help in some situations rendering content in Safari. Could you try with this? " <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover"> "

Comment: Updated the Bin but no difference.

Comment: @SpaceBeers what version do you use? Did you try with the portable version I used?

Comment: can you share image what you exactly want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you need to include compatible transitions in the code.

```
.test {
  background-repeat: space no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red calc(100% - 1px), transparent 100%);
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s linear; /* Safari */
  transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  background-position: left top;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 310px;
}
```

I've heard of other problems too where you need to change the transition code a little but this is what I've gotten.